# Using GetObject to read data in an Access Query into Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, windows-10-desktop

Last year I was greatly helped when someone explained how to use GetObject in Word VBA to read data from an Access Form. I have been using it successfully since then. I would now like to do the same with an Access Query.
I started by mimicking the code I've been using to read Forms. With the Query “CommentSearch” open, and a record selected, including a field called AbbrevTit, I have been trying the following, which I can’t get to work:

```
   Dim app, tx As String
   Set app = GetObject(, "Access.Application")
   tx = app.Queries("CommentSearch")![AbbrevTit]
   Selection.TypeText Text:=tx
   Set app = Nothing
```

I get ‘Object doesn’t support this property or method’
I tried reading different Fields, then created a simple new Query for the purpose. No joy.
Among my References I have Microsoft Forms 2.0 checked and I can’t find an equivalent for Queries so I guess there isn’t one.
How do I use GetObject to read data in an Access Query into Word VBA?

Comment: Pull data from table or query by opening a recordset object. Or set up a merge.

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I may get it to work, but reading data from an Access Form is so much easier via GetObject that I thought there must be an equivalent for Queries.